# How to join three table in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I am making a food donating application. I have three tables in the database namely:

```
user_info
donated_info
accepted_info
```

The attributes of 'user_info' table are:

```
user_id, name, username, password, address, phone, pincode
```

The attributes of 'donated_info' table are:

```
user_id, Food_id, Food_item, No_of_serving, Expiry_date, Expiry_time, Image, status
```

The attributes of 'accepted_info' table are:

```
Food_id, user_id
```

I want to create a module in which the donater gets to view the status of his donations. [By default, the status attribute is set to 'to_accept'. Whenever someone accepts it, the value is changed to 'accepted'. I want to retrieve four columns: name, phone, Food_item, Image. If the Food_item is accepted, the name and phone number of the person who has accepted it will be displayed. Else those two columns will be empty. How can I write a query for this? Any kind of helps will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get stuck with writing your query?

Comment: I wrote a query which just returns the details of the person who is donating it. But I want the details of the user who has accepted if there is any. Can you help me @Shadow

Answer (score 1):

You use a simple Join

```
SELECT name, phone, Food_item, Image
FROM accepted_info a JOIN donated_info d ON u.Food_id= d.Food_id
    JOIN user_info u ON a.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE d.user_id = 1
```

Also try

```
SELECT name, phone, Food_item, Image
FROM donated_info d  LEFT JOIN accepted_info a   ON u.Food_id= d.Food_id 
    JOIN user_info u ON a.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE d.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Actually I want the name and phone number of the person who is accepting it(which is stored in accepted_info)

Comment: i changed my answer

Comment: I'm sorry, it still displays the donater's information @nbk

Comment: i don't see wherr the id from the user is that you want  in your table the hole design makes not that much sense, but you only have one user_id field per table, all seem to link to the same user, so change my query a.user_id = u.user_id a.user_id to the correct column

Comment: Thank you, it was kinda helpful. I just changed the where clause condition to d.user_id because I want the data for a particular donator's food items. Problem solved :) But I can't display the unaccepted columns tho. Maybe I can use a separate query for that.

Comment: I added a version where all donations are display independent of the of the acceptance. but you see how it is done.

Comment: But it returns an empty set when none of the user's donation are accepted. Which means unaccepted food details are not returned

Comment: no it shows all donation whether or not they are acepted please make a sample on https://dbfiddle.uk and show me whart you have as data, this go nowhere. withou it

Comment: From user_id = 11, I have made two donations that yet to be accepted. I ran the query and it doesn't return anything

Comment: make a fiddle **please**

Comment: I used an union instead:) ```SELECT name, phone, Food_item, Image
FROM accepted_info a JOIN donated_info d ON a.Food_id= d.Food_id
    JOIN user_info u ON a.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE d.user_id = 11
UNION ALL SELECT null, null, Food_item, Image FROM donated_info WHERE user_id = 11 AND status='to_accept'``` Thanks @nbk

Comment: thta doesn't seem right, are you sure you don't want to a dbfiddle?

Comment: Pardon me. What is meant by 'dbfiddle'? Btw, the query returned what I actually wanted

Comment: as i wrote before post your tables and data here  https://dbfiddle.uk/